#  CSS Nav bar resize issue

Tags: html, css

So I'm aware that this is a confusing question. Basically, I've got two divs at the top of the page that include navigation and a search bar.

I have a full container 
        #containPage 
    width:1000px;
    margin:0 auto;
    }

for the page that is fixed width. This doesn't end until the end, I think,  and there are two smaller containers for a layout, both float right and left.

When I resize the page in a browser, the layout at the top moves and changes the positioning, which I don't want to happen.

Any ideas?

here is the link: it's being even screwier right now and has the navigation links way to the right, so maybe someone could help with that too.

http://www.sophisticatedmoose.com/nerdery/

- Resizing horizontally in Chrome and Firefox for Mac. If you scroll to the right, I'm supposed to have a nav bar underneath the search page with home, about, news, and contact. Last I checked- and I'm clearing the cache - it was waaay off on the left along with the footer.

Working on an image. I need reputation 10 to put one in. I've got it though.

Comment: Can you link to a live example?

Comment: yes - it's being even screwier right now and has the navigation links way to the right, so maybe someone could help with that too. 

http://www.sophisticatedmoose.com/nerdery/

Comment: When you resize horizontally or vertically? Vertically does nothing for me, horizontally, it stays in the center, which I find to be nice.

Comment: what browser is this in? I just tried it in Chrome and resized and nothing weird happened.

Comment: That website looks pretty freaking good, so maybe you could include pictures that clearly point out what *is* happening, and what *should* happen.

Comment: hrm...now that you mention it, the links are little bit too far to the right, in FF 3.6.

Comment: It only is bugged on Mac. It is fine in Linux/Windows.

Comment: Hmm. I have mac, that's interesting. It looks fine in Dreamweaver CS5 as well.

Comment: Well, you do have a negative width in `#nav`...which gets ignored by Chrome in Windows...

Comment: would something like `postion: absolute` fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this odd construct in your CSS:

```
#containPage { /*page I am in you*/
    width:223%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

The margin setting is fine and sensible but the width is rather, um, strange. The `#containPage` element is, essentially, the entire page so it is naturally as wide as the browser window, then the 223% is applied and the page itself becomes more than twice as wide as the browser window. Then, all the block elements that are immediate children of `#containPage` will be over twice as wide as the window unless you specify or imply a width in some other way.

In particular, the `#NavRRT` element will be too wide and the menu inside `#NavRRT` will float to the right all the way out of the window and you'll have to scroll horizontally to see it. Similar positioning strangeness happens with `#footer`.

Start by getting rid of the `width:223%` on `#containPage`. The page looks fine in Safari and Chrome if I turn off just that single piece of CSS.

**UPDATE**: You might want to add another `<div>` inside `#containPage`, then add `max-width`, `min-width`, and `margin: 0 auto` to that to keep the main content centered and reasonably sized. Everything that is currently inside `#containPage` would go inside this new `<div>`. If you go with this approach then you probably won't need any CSS at all on `#containPage`, it would just need to be around to help center the "real" page.

Comment: I thought I got rid of that. Hmm. What do you recommend putting as a width in its place?

Comment: @C.N.: You don't need a width on `#containerPage` at all. I added an update about putting another `<div>` inside your top level container to constrain the content width.

Comment: Okay, so now the issue seems to be that my css file won't update. So completely different, but hopefully this will work. You are very helpful.

Comment: @C.N.: The current version looks good to me in Safari, Chrome, and Firefox (and even resizes nicely, hooray!). Do you have an old copy of the CSS file stuck in your cache?

Comment: @Mu hooray! I've been clearing my cache like a crazy person, so I'm glad to know that it works for someone on the outside. I'm going to try restarting all of my browsers.

Comment: @C.N.: You can try adding a `?cache-hack=some_random_number` to the end of the CSS path when debugging, that will usually trick the browser into not caching it at all.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the margin-left from your nav LIs (it's inherited from `li`) and remove their widths.

```
#nav li { margin-left: 0; width: auto !important; }
```

Comment: You can just remove `padding-left: 95px`, right? Also, be aware that this changes a bit how it looks in Chrome...might not matter...

Comment: I think the nav li fix may have just worked. Hang on to your hats.

Comment: haha. It didn't work :( it didn't seem to do much of anything except make the nav lis more relevant.

Comment: Neither did removing padding-left

Comment: The width of the LI nav items is defined by the image. There is no need for a CSS width.